# Layout.mobile.cshtml suddenly stopped working -- should not be cache related

Tags: layout, asp.net-mvc-4

I left on Friday with my application working in dev mode....I came in this morning and the Layout.Mobile.chtml was NOT being used.....THIS IS DEV MODE so I still starting the web server each time.... I read about a similar issue related to the cache....but I don't see how this could be related to my problem as once the web server shuts down the cache is cleared.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 as my development "web server".

Everything was running and I don't see where the problem is nor do I understand where to look next.  Any suggestions of how to diagnosis this problem or where to look would be appreciated.

This is ONLY for the Layout.Mobile.cshtml....when I switch back to the Layout.cshtml it is being called fine....

In my global.asax.cs I have the following set to force firefox to display using the mobile layout:

```
    //The following forces Firefox to use the Mobile View ONLY
    DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("mobile")
    {
        ContextCondition = (context =>
            context.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Mozilla", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    });
```

My _ViewStart.cshtml file is:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

My _Layout.Cshtml is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - Etracs</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")     

 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script> 

       @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) 
    </head>
    <body>


        <header>
             *@  
        </header>

        <div id="body">         
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>


        @Html.Partial("_ViewSwitcher")
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Turning Basin Services</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

My _Layout.Mobile.cshtml is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

      @*  @Styles.Render("~/Content/Mobile/css")  *@
      @*  @Styles.Render("~/Content/jquerymobile/css") *@ 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css" />  

      @*  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")   *@
      @*  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerymobile")  *@
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script> 
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
            });
        </script>

        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) 
    </head> 

    <body> 

        <div data-role="page" data-theme="c">

            <div data-role="header"> 
                @RenderSection("backbtn", false)       
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
                @RenderSection("Home", false)
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
               @*     @RenderSection("featured", false) *@
                    @RenderBody()       
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer">
                   <h4>  @Html.Partial("_ViewSwitcher")  &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Turning Basin Services</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

In my views I am usually setting up the view to impliclity map to the Layout using viewstart.... however, my .Login.Mobile.cshtml hardwires the assocaiation to the mobile layout as follows:

```
@model TBS.Etracs.Web.Main.Models.LoginModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.Mobile.cshtml";
}



    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<section id="loginForm">
   @* @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) { *@
    @using (Html.BeginForm ("Login")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="UserName">UserName:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>


            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="ProgramMode">ProgramMode</label>
                <select name="ProgramMode" id="ProgramMode">
                    <option value="VW">VW</option>
                    <option value="Porsche">Porsche</option>
                    <option value="Bentley">Bentley</option>
                </select>
            </div>

         <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="ConnectionMode">ConnectionMode</label>
                <select name="ConnectionMode" id="ConnectionMode">
                    <option value="Production">Production</option>
                    <option value="Test">Test</option>
                </select>
            </div>


          <input type="submit" value="Log in" />

        </div>

    }
</section>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: I just confirmed I have the FixedDisplayModes nuget package installed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Glimpse I found that that the _layout.mobile.cshtml was still being called and included....the problem was that it was not working....which relates to a problem I had earlier.....

In my _Layout.Mobile.chtml I went back to the following code and my layout is now working

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css" /> 

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

I used this to replace the following lines in my _layout.Mobile.cshtml

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css" />  


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

The big question that I am VERY confused about is what happened .... this prevous worked for several days and then quit working..... Input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see you acknowledged you didn't believe this was related to the cache - but I'm adding this here since it's critical to be aware of when using mobile views.

The caching bug is explained here

> Dave Ward:
>
> Something everyone should be aware of when using MVC 4's mobile view
> support is that there's a bug in the RTM version that results in the
> wrong view being rendered for mobile devices after the view falls out
> of the resolution cache the first time. The tricky part is that you
> won't notice this in debug mode or until 15 minutes of inactivity in
> release mode, so it's incredibly easy to let the buggy behavior slip
> into production. There's an easy fix on NuGet, which Rick Anderson
> covers here:
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/09/17/asp-net-mvc-4-mobile-caching-bug-fixed.aspx

See also comments in this post
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx

If you have a custom view engine (like i do) you can just change the base class after installing the nuget package:

```
public class SiteIdentityViewEngine : Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedRazorViewEngine, IVirtualPathFactory
```